# How to properly format tables using css

Tags: html, css

I want the outer borders of my table be dashed, while the inner borders be solid. So I made these css codes for my `normal-table`, but whole table border is solid.

```css
.zulu-post .zulu-content .normal-table{
    color: #444444;
    border: 1px dashed #444444;
}

.zulu-post .zulu-content .normal-table td, .normal-table tr{
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #444444;
}
```

```html
<table border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" class="normal-table" style="width:500px;">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Table Name</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Make sure that Stylesheet Classes is normal-table</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Text Here...</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Is it possible to add your relevant HTML code as well please?

Comment: @kevinb. finished

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one way of doing what you want:

Basically you add border `left and top` to all `<td>` tags and than remove the border from the sides of the table, and you use dashed border on `<table>`.

```css
.normal-table {
  color: #444444;
  border: 1px dashed #444444;
}

.normal-table td {
  padding: 10px;
  border-left: 1px solid #444444;
  border-top: 1px solid #444444;
}

.normal-table td:first-child {
  border-left: none;
}

.normal-table tr:first-child td {
  border-top: none;
}
```

```html
<table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="0" class="normal-table" style="width:500px;">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Table Name</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Make sure that Stylesheet Classes is normal-table</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Text Here...</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

1st make use of `border-collpase:collapse`, this `collapse` the `table border` to `single` border then do styling part for `table, tbody, tr` and such.

```css
.normal-table {
  border: 2px solid red;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

tr {
  border: 2px dashed red;
}
```

```html
<table border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" class="normal-table" style="width:500px;">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Table Name</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Make sure that Stylesheet Classes is normal-table</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Text Here...</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use divs as an alternative:

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  border: medium dashed darkgray;
  display: table;
}
.cell {
  width: 30%;
  border: thin solid red;
  height: 50px;
  display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
<div class='cell'></div>
<div class='cell'></div>
<div class='cell'></div>
</div>
```